# On click needs 2 click to run other library's function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When clicked on HTML element, it needs another click to run the `filemanager` function!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click",".lfm-image",function() {
       $(this).filemanager('image');
    });
});
```

Comment: I would imagine because the `filemanager()` plugin creates events itself, so you most likely need to instantiate it on load, not in a click handler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Elements are dynamically created and added to DOM, how could I do that ?

Comment: In that case you would need to manually instantiate the `filemanager()` plugin on the new elements at the point you create them. A delegated event handler will not work in that case - assuming the plugin isn't using one internally. Given you're having this issue, I would assume it's not.

Answer (score 0):

The inside code "$(document).on.." is event delegation already, remove it out of $(document).ready. the click event will work outside $(document).ready...

Comment: Note that we also use doc.ready to say "run this code when everything else has loaded" which has the advantage of reducing the apparent page load - in the case of a single event delegation, this won't make much difference - but could add substantial time to be ready if code is taken out of doc.ready just because it doesn't *have* to be there (depending on where the code is etc)